# TTS - Diphone database

Tags: speech-processing, speech-synthesis

I am working on text to speech conversion. I have done speech synthesis by

concatenation of phonemes.The transition between phonemes is not

smooth.I want to shift to diphone synthesis.  Where can I find diphone

database for the English language. Any other alternative might help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at the diphone synthesizer resources in the [Festival Speech Synthesis](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/) framework?

The state of the art for Text2Speech (though still not practical for production due to GPU compute requirements) is Deepmind's [WaveNet](https://deepmind.com/blog/wavenet-generative-model-raw-audio/).

Their results are definitely smoother than concatenative or parametric methods.  Good luck!